# What is the added value of using Tiles and Thymeleaf in the same project?

Tags: tiles, thymeleaf

I've opened the Spring tutorials and the messages-jc project uses both. Why is that? They seem pretty similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiles is used for providing a layout. Specifically Tiles provides a simple way to display all the content that is shared (i.e. the navigation) across the views. This is preferable to using  something simple like includes because includes would have to be updated within each of the views where as tiles can be mapped externally.